# Can I recover data that disappeared when deleting a VirtualBox VM snapshot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

I removed a snapshot of a VirtualBox VM. When I went back into the VM I saw that some data that I created during the lifetime of the snapshot was missing.

Can I get the data back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you delete a snapshot via VirtualBox itself you get the following message (on Windows 7):

> "Deleting the snapshot will cause the state information saved in it to be lost, and disk data spread over several images files that VirtualBox has created together with the snapshot will be **merged into one file**..."

So deleting a snapshot **via VirtualBox** will not delete your data (it will be merged with the "big"-VDI file).

But if you delete the snapshot by deleting the associated `.vdi` (as in `rm my_snapshot.vdi`) all data in it will be lost (that's the data you added/changed since creating that snapshot until you create the next one).

If you want data back from such snapshot **you need to recover the file first** before you can access the data again. If you have multiple snapshots and you deleted one in between it can really mess up the guest-OS.

Comment: Thanks @Rik for your answer, you are well correct about this, and I got the message that you showed. Unfortunately, the folder that was on the desktop was not there (I am using Widows 7 Professional and VirtualBox is used to host Linux Ubuntu 12.04). Wired, ain't it?

Comment: I am running some heavy computations in C++ and Matlab (The run took more than a week). During running,I tried to access the Linux (just put the password, to unlock) and the screen halted, black, but, everything was fine with Windows. So, I created a snapshot, and it helped me to access (everything was normal). Two days later, it halted again, so, I had to create another snapshot (I hope that wasn't a stupid idea), and I got access again. Later, I could not run anything, not even a terminal, nor htop. After the run ended, I removed the snapshot and the data was gone.

Comment: For me the snapshots are in `%userprofile%/VirtualBox VMs` and then the subdirectory of you VM and the subdirectory `Snapshots`. You can look if there are some file left from a previous snapshot. Which snapshot did you delete? Only the last? (That's the one above current state) How did you "remove" the snapshot?

Comment: I used Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager to remove the sanpshots, very simple. I have already checked those directories, and they were empty. After deleting snapshot2, the data was lost, then, I deleted snapshot1 that has some data but was not lost (this is a stack like structure). To tell you the truth, I am already running the whole experiment again to get the data, but,  I am curious of what happened. (After snapshot1,  I am back to the original state) So, maybe there is some bug in removing multi snapshots.

Answer (score 0):

yes,when you delete the snapshot your data will will on strong

maybe some data recovery software can help you

but,often a snapshot is very big...

so i think in the end you can't get back your data.

Comment: Well, I deleted two snapshots, the data was lost in the first, but, another data was not lost in the other? Very strange!